# choose among 3 different maps on condition

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, stdmap

I have a 3 different C++ map declarations.

```
map<string, string> map1; 
map<string, int> map2; 
map<string, double> map3;
```

I would like to use one of the maps depending on the condition. Let's say

```
if (map_value == "map1") { default_map = map1; } 
else if (map_value == "map2") { default_map = map2; } 
else { default_map = map3; }
```

My problem is I do not know how to declare the `default_map` in C++ which can be changed according to the condition. I am expecting something like `map<Object,Object> default_map` declaration in C++.

Edit. 
I chose `string`, `int`, and `double` as hypothetical objects. The actual `map1`, `map2` and `map3` stores function pointers. Depending on the value inside maps, I call different functions. The function signatures are the same, but those function pointers come from different classes. It is, in essence, `class A` has `void funcA(string);`, `class B` has `void funcA(string);` and `class C` has `void funcA(string);` and `funcA` is implemented differently depending on the class.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you planning on using `default_map`?

Comment: In other words, what would you do with your hypothetical `Object`?

Comment: `variant<std::map<std::string, std::string>, std::map<std::string, int>, std::map<std::string, double>>` ?

Comment: @Kerrek SB I chose `string, int, and double` as hypothetical objects. The actual map1, map2 and map3 stores function pointers. Depending on the value inside maps, I call different functions.

Comment: @Jarod42 I am not sure how to use Variant. Can I declare `default_map` as variant and assign `default_map` to `map1, map2 or map3`?

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do, but it is a possibility. maybe not the good one though.

Comment: OK, but how do you know which and how many function arguments to provide if the function depends on a dynamic condition? Do you want to recheck the condition at each use?

Comment: The function signatures are the same, but those function pointers come from different classes. It is, in essence, `class A` has `funcA(string)`, `class B` has `funcA(string)` and `class C` has `funcA(string)` and `funcA` is implemented differently depending on the class.

Comment: @pseudo: **Now** we have a completely different question for which I can think of a very nice answer. If you edit your question, I can post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your clarification in the comments, I can provide the following suggestion:

```
std::function<R(K, T1, T2, T3)> look_up_and_call;

X x;
Y y;
Z z;

if (map_value == "map1") {
  look_up_and_call =
      [&x, &map1](K key T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3) { return (x.*map1[key])(t1, t2, t3); }
} else if (map_value == "map2") {
  look_up_and_call =
      [&y, &map2](K key T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3) { return (y.*map2[key])(t1, t2, t3); }
} else {
  look_up_and_call =
      [&z, &map3](K key T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3) { return (z.*map3[key])(t1, t2, t3); }
}
```

Now for any given map key `key` you can call the bound function as so:

```
R result = look_up_and_call(key, arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

I've simplified the code a bit, e.g. we assume that the map elements are always non-null member function pointers. You can adapt this scheme to allow for other kinds of pointers, and real code should probably deal with non-existence of the key. You can also write analogous functions for adding elements to the map.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Do you mind explaining the `[&x, &map1](K key T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3)` part in the answer and link documentation where I can read more about that? I will accept this as answer then.

Comment: @pseudo: This is a lambda expression.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

C++ has strong enough typing that you will have quite a bit of difficulty doing what you're asking for here.

I can see a couple of obvious possibilities. One would be to use something like a [Boost Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/variant.html) to store the value:

```
std::map<string, boost::variant<string, int, double> > mapN;
```

This will let you associate any one of a `string`, an `int` or a `double` with a given string as the key. The variant type is basically a discriminated union--that is, it can store any one of the specified types, and has a field telling which one is present in any particular instance.

Another possibility would be to have what looks like a single function that's overloaded for all three value types, so you can have uniform-looking code across call sites:

```
void save_map(std::string const &key, std::string const & val) { 
    map1[key] = val;
}

void save_map(std::string const &key, int val) { 
    map2[key] = val;
}

void save_map(std::string const &key, double val) { 
   map3[key] = val;
}
```

This lets code like `save_map("foo", bar);` work for `bar` being any of the three specified types (plus implicit conversions). Note, however, that what may initially seem like the most obvious design for retrieving values won't work. In particular, you can't overload on return type, so you can't have something like:

```
std::string get_map(std::string);
int get_map(std::string);
double get_map(std::string);
```

You can't overload on return type, so the overloaded type will have to be passed as a parameter:

```
void get_map(std::string const &key, string &dest);
void get_map(std::string const &key, int &dest);
void get_map(std::string const &key, double &dest);
```

As to which of these (or some other possibility) makes sense: that'll depend on what you're really trying to accomplish--something you haven't told us enough about to give a meaningful answer.

Comment: Since C++17 you can directly use std::variant (#include <variant>).